# Предикаты и дженерики

Tags: java, generics

Начал разбираться с предикатами и дженериками. И вот у меня есть вот такой вот статический метод:

```
public static <T> int findFirst(List<T> list, int begin, int end, Predicate<? extends T> p){
        for(int i = begin; i <= end; i++)
            if(p.test(list.get(i)))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
```

Но среда разработки выдает ошибку

```
T cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends T
```

Не могу понять почему, ведь  означает класс Т и его потомки, почему `p.test()` не принимает элемент листа

Comment: суть метода в том, чтобы найти первый элемент отвечающий условию

Comment: а там не `Predicate<? super T>` требуется?

Comment: в том то и тело, не понимаю почему с Predicate<? super T> работает, а с Predicate<? extends T> p нет

Answer (score 3):

Предположим, у нас имеется иерархия классов:

```
class K { public byte k_value; }  // суперкласс для T
class T : K { public int t_value; }  // T унаследован от K
class Q : T { public long q_value; }  // Q унаследован от T
```

Когда мы пишем параметр `Predicate<? extends T>`, это означает, что можно в этот параметр передать методы со следующими сигнатурами:

```
bool ConditionT(T value);
bool ConditionQ(Q value);
```

т.е. параметр передаваемого метода должен иметь тип `T` или тип любого ***потомка*** `T` (в данном случае подходит `Q`).

Предположим, в ваш метод `findFirst` мы передали последний вариант: `ConditionQ`.

Что произойдёт в этом случае? А получится при вызове `p.test()` попытка передать объект типа `T` в том месте, где требуется тип `Q`. В результате получим ошибку приведения типов, что логично: в конкретно данном примере, у объекта `Q` можно ожидать наличие поля `q_value`, а объект `T` его не содержит - так что передавать нельзя.

Когда же пишем параметр `Predicate<? super T>`, это означает, что можно в этот параметр передать методы со следующими сигнатурами:

```
bool ConditionK(K value);
bool ConditionT(T value);
```

т.е. параметр передаваемого метода должен иметь тип `T` или тип любого ***предка*** `T` (в данном случае подходит `K`).

Предположим, в ваш метод `findFirst` мы передали первый вариант: `ConditionK`.

В этом случае, при вызове `p.test()` имеется попытка передать объект типа `T` в том месте, где требуется тип `K`. Попытка будет *успешной*, поскольку класс `T` является производным от `K` и гарантированно содержит в себе интерфес типа `K`. В конкретно данном примере можно говорить о том, что не только объект типа `K` содержит поле `k_value`, но и объект типа `T` тоже (в силу наследования).

Answer (score 0):

Например, в качестве `Т` передается Person, а (`? extends Person`) будет `Student`, у которого есть поля, которых нет у `Person`, но в методе `test()` надо именно по этим полям задать логику проверки. Как быть?